# VBA Excel - перечисление слов из разных ячеек через запятые и союз «и»

Tags: строки, excel, vba, макрос

Возьмём, например, девять ячеек, в каждом будет по одному слову или выражению. Ячейки могут быть и пустыми!
В десятой ячейке будут записываться все слова через запятую, а самое последнее слово — через союз «и». Суть в том, чтобы по условию искать последнюю и неединственную непустую ячейку, и если она соответствует условиям, перед её содержимым в ячейке вывода вместо запятой писать союз «и».
Возможные примеры:

Ввод:

```
жир
парень
дом
автобус
город
кольцо
дети
велосипед
фонарь
```

Вывод:
`жир, парень, дом, автобус, город, кольцо, дети, велосипед и фонарь`

Если мы удалим пару слов из этого списка (тире обозначает пустую ячейку):

```
-
парень
дом
-
город
кольцо
дети
-
-
```

получится: `парень, дом, город, кольцо и дети`

Если в вводе только одна ячейка содержит слово или выражение, то в выводе должно получиться, например: `город`

Comment: Если версия младше 2016, нарисуйте под это дело пользовательскую функцию - и проще, и быстрее, чем городить многоэтажное безобразие в виде формулы. А если версия 2016 или свежее, то в них есть функция ОБЪЕДИНИТЬ (TEXTJOIN).

Comment: 2007, как ни странно. И да, я к макросу и клоню

Comment: *я к макросу и клоню* А у нас у всех, как назло, ХШ на профилактике...

Comment: а что такое ХШ?

Comment: ХШ - это Хрустальный Шар.

Answer (score 1):

```
Function my_concat(source As Range) As String
Dim tmp As String, onecell As Range
For Each onecell In source
    tmp = Trim(tmp & " " & onecell.Value)
Next
my_concat = StrReverse(Replace(Replace(StrReverse(tmp), " ", " ,"), " ,", " и ", , 1))
End Function
```

Спокойно съест и диапазоны-многострочники.

Да - пробелы в значениях весьма нежелательны. Я бы даже сказал - недопустимы.

Comment: Я о `Trim` не подумал :)  Так, конечно, лучше. Можно не в цикле, а в конце: `Application.Trim`

Comment: @vikttur Наверное, `WorksheetFunction.Trim`? Да, можно.

Comment: можно так, как я записал, То, что функция листа, редактор понимает. `...Replace(Application.Trim(StrReverse(tmp)),...`

Comment: @vikttur *То, что функция листа, редактор понимает* Возможно, зависит от версии. У меня на 2010 Офисе ни разу не понимает...

Comment: Так и у меня 2010. Работает. И чистить правильнее сразу (выше я неправильно записал): `...Replace(StrReverse(Application.Trim(tmp)),...`

Answer (score 0):

```
Function fMergeWords(rRng As Range) As String
    Dim sTxt As String
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    
    For i = 1 To rRng.Cells.Count
        If rRng(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
            sTxt = sTxt & ", " & rRng(i, 1).Value
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
    If n > 1 Then
        n = InStrRev(sTxt, ",") - 1
        sTxt = Left$(sTxt, n) & " и " & Mid$(sTxt, n + 2)
    End If
    
    fMergeWords = Mid$(sTxt, 3)
End Function
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]